# Showing images or alternatively text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've created a list of images and I would like to add a button, to show text instead of images. Something like "Show images" "Show text".

How I can make it possible?

Comment: what HTML and CSS code do you currently have? - Please share.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with Javascript/jQuery by having the text initially hidden for instance. It is not possible to handle click events with HTML or CSS.

---

For example you could do something like this in jQuery:

`$('button_that_hides_image_shows_text').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('image_to_hide').css('display', 'none');
    $('hidden_text').css('display', 'block');
});`

You could also make the button toggle from image to text:

`$('button_that_hides_image_shows_text').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('image_to_hide').toggleClass('class_that_hides');
    $('hidden_text').toggleClass('class_that_hides');
});`

by having the class_that_hides initially on the text

`.class_that_hides {
    display:none;
}`

*If you need extra information, please ask me*